# I am not getting desired output in reverse a number code in C++

Tags: c++, reverse, palindrome

I am trying to find a reversed number and check that it is a palindrome or not from a different approach but I was getting a right reversed number up to two digits and if the digits are more than two then I am getting wrong output. I cannot understand why is this so as I think my code is right.

below is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num, rem, t, add;
    cin >> t;

    while (t--) {
        int total = 0, count = 0, i = 1, quo = 0;
        cin >> num;
        quo = num;

        while (quo > 9) //count determiner
        {
            quo = quo / 10;
            ++count;
        }

        while (count >= 0) //reverse number saved in total
        {
            int den = pow(10, i);
            rem = (num % den);
            add = rem / pow(10, i - 1);

            total = total + (add * pow(10, count));

            ++i;
            --count;
        }

        if (total == num) {
            cout << "Palindrome"
                 << "\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Not a Palindrome"
                 << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please help me to know where I am going wrong in this code.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, with different rules and semantics. Please only tag the language your code is actually written in. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You don't need `pow` to reverse a number.  As a matter of fact, it is remarkably simple.

Comment: Also, can the number be negative?  If it is, your routine won't work.

Comment: What did you learn while using your debugger?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is an important skill that every programmer should be able to use.  Using StackOverflow as your debugger is orders of magnitude slower than debugging with a debugger.  You'd have been able to reconsider "I think my code is right" very quickly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code. so i assumed by myself and wrote code.I assume that there will be no negative number and if there will be then i rid off negative sign. please provide desire output for negative number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //int num, rem, t, add;
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    while (t-- > 0) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int num = abs(n);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            n = abs(n);
        }
        int res{ 0 };
        while (n > 0)
        {
            res *= 10;
            int rem = n % 10;
            res += rem;
            n /= 10;
        }

        if (res  == num) {
            cout << "Palindrome"
                 << "\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Not a Palindrome"
                 << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ouptut of above code:

```
4
-191
Palindrome
232
Palindrome
123
Not a Palindrome
561
Not a Palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to reverse a number is very convoluted, as it uses `pow` (a floating point function) to get each digit.  This is totally unnecessary if you look for the pattern of how to reverse an integer.

Simple addition, multiplying by 10, and modulus is all that's necessary to do this.  Note that I created a function, so that it is easy to follow:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int reverse_int(int num)
{
   int total = 0;
   // take care of negative by using absolute value
   int tempNum = abs(num);
   while (tempNum > 0)
   {
       total = (total*10) + (tempNum % 10);
       tempNum /= 10;
   }
   return (num < 0)?-total:total;
}

int main()
{    
   int num = 1234321;
   if ( num == reverse_int(num))
      std::cout << num << " is a palindrome\n";
   else      
      std::cout << num << " is not a palindrome\n";
      
   int num2 = 123;
   if ( num2 == reverse_int(num2))
      std::cout << num2 << " is a palindrome\n";
   else      
      std::cout << num2 << " is not a palindrome\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1234321 is a palindrome
123 is not a palindrome
```

The loop is very simple if you follow what is going on:

```
number = 123 (Assume this is our number)
total = 0;

Loop while (number > 0):

First iteration:
total = (total * 10) + (number % 10) --> (0 * 10) + (0 % 3) --> 3
number /= 10 --> 12

Second iteration:
total = (total * 10) + (number % 10) = (3 * 10) + (12 % 10) --> 32
number /= 10 --> 1

Third iteration:
total = (total * 10) + (number % 10) = (32 * 10) + (1 % 10) --> 321
number /= 10 --> 0 (Stop the loop)

total = 321
```

At the end of the function, we just return the value, and make it negative if the original number was negative.

Comment: if you would make `while (tempNum != 0)` you actually would consider negative numbers and could get rid of the negative check at the end of the reverse_int and the `abs` call function. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6d1f40ddffab7f7

Comment: yeah, you are right that the using of pow function is unnecessary and the code you have written I have already solved this problem of with this method, i was just trying to find the solution of this problem from another method and i cannot understand why the code is not working as mathematically i found that code correct but that code is giving correct reversed number upto 2 digits and for more than 2 digits it is giving wrong output means wrong reverse number. And that's what my question is "why is my code not working even all the thing looks correct from my side".

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the input was valid. So if we leave that aside and assume the input is a valid integer then you can use a `std::string` and reverse it via `std::reverse`:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::string reverse = input;
    std::reverse(reverse.begin(),reverse.end());
    if (input == reverse) std::cout << "Palindrome number"
}
```